# How to use very simple http-auth based authentication in turbogears2?

Tags: turbogears2

After disabling the default configuration of `repoze.who` by removing all the `base_config.sa_auth...` and `base_config.auth_backend` from `config/app_.cfg.py`it should be possible to configure repoze.who as middleware in `config/middleware.py`.

so i created a file `config/auth.py` like this:

```
from logging import getLogger

from repoze.who.middleware import PluggableAuthenticationMiddleware
from repoze.who.classifiers import default_challenge_decider, default_request_classifier

from repoze.who.plugins.basicauth import BasicAuthPlugin
from repoze.who.plugins.htpasswd import HTPasswdPlugin, plain_check

def add_auth(app):
    htpasswd = HTPasswdPlugin('/.../htpasswd', plain_check)
    authenticators = [('htpasswd', htpasswd)]

    base_auth = BasicAuthPlugin('Inventory DB')
    challengers = [('base_auth', base_auth)]
    identifiers = [('base_auth', base_auth)]

    mdproviders = []

    log_stream = getLogger('auth')

    app_with_mw = PluggableAuthenticationMiddleware(
        app,
        identifiers,
        authenticators,
        challengers,
        mdproviders,
        default_request_classifier,
        default_challenge_decider,
        log_stream,
        )
    return app_with_mw
```

where plain_text passwords are used just for testing. Then, in `config/middleware.py` this function is imported and applied to the `app` as the last step in the `make_app` function.

```
from invdb.config.app_cfg import base_config
from invdb.config.environment import load_environment
from auth import add_auth

__all__ = ['make_app']
make_base_app = base_config.setup_tg_wsgi_app(load_environment)
def make_app(global_conf, full_stack=True, **app_conf):
    app = make_base_app(global_conf, full_stack=True, **app_conf)
    app = add_auth(app)
    return app
```

The problem is now, that the authentication does not really work. Controllers that do not require any authentication don't challenge. A controller with `allow_only = tg.predicate.not_anonymous` will challenge a http-authentication. But even if plain_check returns `True` the login is instantly forgotten and the challenge is displayed again. `tg.request.identity` stays `None`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a far easier solution that replacing the whole authentication stack with a custom middleware. As mentioned by [authentication documentation](http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/turbogears/authentication.html) you can configure the authentication stack from your `app_cfg.py` itself.

For example if you want to force the basic auth usage you just need to set the `challengers`, `identifiers` and `authenticators` and then return the data to fill `tg.request.identity` using the `authmetadata`

Here is a sample app_cfg for basic auth (remember to remove any other `basic_config.sa_auth` 
entry or it might crash for unexpected parameters):

```py
# Name our custom auth backend, if this is None TG will
# disable the whole authentication stack.
base_config.auth_backend = 'htpasswd'

from tg.configuration.auth import TGAuthMetadata

#This tells to TurboGears how to retrieve the data for your user
class ApplicationAuthMetadata(TGAuthMetadata):
    def __init__(self, sa_auth):
        self.sa_auth = sa_auth

    def get_user(self, identity, userid):
        # As we use htpasswd for authentication
        # we cannot lookup the user in a database,
        # so just return a fake user object
        from tg.util import Bunch
        return Bunch(display_name=userid, user_name=userid)

    def get_groups(self, identity, userid):
        # If the user is manager we give him the
        # managers group, otherwise no groups
        if userid == 'manager':
            return ['managers']
        else:
            return []

    def get_permissions(self, identity, userid):
        return []

base_config.sa_auth.authmetadata = ApplicationAuthMetadata(base_config.sa_auth)

from repoze.who.plugins.basicauth import BasicAuthPlugin
from repoze.who.plugins.htpasswd import HTPasswdPlugin, plain_check

# Use htpasswd for checking user credentials, remember to write the password in clear
# text as we are using the plain_check function to check them.
base_config.sa_auth.authenticators = [('htpasswd', HTPasswdPlugin('./passwd_file', plain_check))]

# Use BasicAuth plugin to ask user for credentials, this will replace
# the whole login form and cookie based authentication
base_auth = BasicAuthPlugin('MyTGApp')
base_config.sa_auth.challengers = [('basicauth', base_auth)]
base_config.sa_auth.identifiers = [('basicauth', base_auth)]

# Disable the login form, it won't work anyway as the credentials
# for basic auth must be provided through the browser itself
base_config.sa_auth.form_identifies = False
```

Comment: thx, great solution. I have thought about creating a fake user objects and fake groups, but deemed it to complicated for this task.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by amol is propably how you should do it. Anyhow, here is the solution i have found in the meantime: Do not use the builtin `predicate.not_anonymous`. This seems to rely on parts of `repoze.what` or `AuthMetaData` which are not configured. So i invented my own predicate:

```
class identified_user(predicates.Predicate):
    def evaluate(self, environ, credentials):
        if environ.get('repoze.who.identity') is None:
            self.unmet()
```